# A wiki of internet resources

Tags: discussion

I think it could be useful and attractive to have a CW list of bike-related internet URLs: excluding LBSs and locale-specific cycling groups; but including manufacturers (whether or not they sell via internet); and including retailers who sell via the internet; and perhaps including blogs and magazines and user groups and any sites like this one; and bike culture (comics, velominati, etc.); and encyclopaedia-like articles and sites (Wikipedia, Sheldon Brown); and pictures. Perhaps one URL per answer so that people can up/down vote each one.

Do you agree or foresee a problem?